# Partial View variables are empty when I post the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have three views each container a table and all three have the same filter functionality.

I have created a partial view called filter which will be rendered on each of the three views (saves replicating the same filter functionality)

Below is how my view is currently constructed

```
@model SomeApplication.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Hierarchy";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Hierarchy</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Hierarchy", "Dealer", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Filter.cshtml", @Model)
   <p>
    <button type="submit" value="Filter"></button>
  </p>
}
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Dealer Name</th>
        <th>Commission Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.DealerHierarchy)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.DealerName
            </td>
            <td>
                @String.Format("{0:n0}", item.CommissionAmount)
                @*@item.CommissionAmount*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

I pass down the model ProjectViewModel to the partial view, partial view below

```
@model SomeApplication.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel

<div class="filter-container">

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.FromDate, new { @placeholder = "From Date", @Id = "txtFromDate" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.ToDate, new { @placeholder = "To Date", @id = "txtToDate" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.SelectedPaymentStatus, Model.Filter.PaymmentStatus, new { @ID = "drpPaymentStatus" })
</div>
```

And this is my controller that it posts to.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Hierarchy(ProjectViewModel vm)
    {

        DateTime? fromDate = vm.Filter.FromDate;

        return View(vm);
    }
```

When I enter some values into fromdate and todate and press submit the values are always null I have followed a tutorial but it seems like I have gone wrong at some point any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the html rendered by `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter.FromDate, ..)`. It should have `<input type="text" name="Filter.FromDate" ..>`. Why are you doing `.. new { @Id = "txtFromDate" }`? Do you have some javascript associated with this control? Is the date you are entering in a valid format that can be converted to `DateTime`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've removed the id tags from the attributes, below is the HTML which gets rendered  <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field FromDate must be a date." id="Filter_FromDate" name="Filter.FromDate" placeholder="From Date" type="text" value="" />

    <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ToDate must be a date." id="Filter_ToDate" name="Filter.ToDate" placeholder="To Date" type="text" value="" />

Comment: @StephenMuecke still have the same issue though

Comment: That looks fine. I would add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property and include the relevant scripts for unobtrusive validation in the main view. It could be that the dates are not in the right format for binding. You can always check `Request.Form` in the POST method to see what value was posted back.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm looking in the form collection when it posts back and nothing is in there.....

Comment: @StephenMuecke ignore that, I've got it working now